# Creating new dictionaries using keys from main dict[BEGINNER]

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, slice

I'm trying to check whether a specific key ends with ":F" or ":M", so i can create new dictionaries called male and female.

```
d = {'Jane:F': 3, 'Tom:M': 2, 'Jeff:M': 5, 'Mary:F': 3}      #initial dict
male = {'Tom': 2, 'Jeff': 5}      #required output
female = {'Jane': 3, 'Mary': 3}      #required output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the key by `:` and then check for `M` and/or `F`:

```
d = {'Jane:F': 3, 'Tom:M': 2, 'Jeff:M': 5, 'Mary:F': 3}

male, female = {}, {}
for k, v in d.items():
    k, gender = k.split(':')
    if gender == 'M':
        male[k] = v
    else:
        female[k] = v

print(male)
print(female)
```

Prints:

```
{'Tom': 2, 'Jeff': 5}
{'Jane': 3, 'Mary': 3}
```

---

Another version using dict-comprehensions:

```
male = {k.split(':')[0]: v for k, v in d.items() if k.endswith(':M')}
female = {k.split(':')[0]: v for k, v in d.items() if k.endswith(':F')}
```